# Sqlite Swift Create and Run Query

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I have a query built like this:

```
let query = devices.select(assetTag)
                .order(assetTag.desc)
                .limit(5, offset: 1)
```

I just do not know which function to use to run it. Do I run it like this:

`db.execute(query)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is as follows:

```
 let results = try! db.prepare(query)

            for items in results
            {
            print (items)

            }
```